# External Style Sheet not affecting HTML

Tags: html, css

Basically just what the title says. I have an external style sheet linked in my HTML, and it looks like the footer element is *possibly* picking up the change, but none of the other info is. I'm very new to this, so just trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House and Live Music</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href= "javajam.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="menu.html">Menu</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="music.html">Music</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <h2>Relax at JavaJam</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, Gluten-free Pastries</li>
    <li>Organic Salads</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    12010 Garrett Bay Road <br>
    Ellison Bay, WI 54210 <br>
    888-555-5555 <br> <br>
  </div>
</main>
  <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2018 JavaJam Coffee House <br>
      <a href = "mailto: email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the external style sheet:

```html
body {background-color: #FCEBB6;
      color: #221811;
      font-family: verdana;}
      
header {background-color: #D2B48C;
        text-align: center;}
        
h1 {line-height: 200%;}

nav {text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;}
    
footer{background-color: #D2B48C;
      font-size: .60em;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of the HTML and stylesheet respectively, placed them in their own files (index.html and javajam.css), and opened index.html in Chrome and I saw the styles applied. Are the HTML and CSS files siblings of each other? As in, in the same folder? If not you'll want to include the path to the CSS file relative to the HTML file.

Comment: Yes, they're in the same folder and everything. Also using Chrome. It's specifically the background colors in the body, header, and footer that seem to be missing. Are these showing up for you?

Comment: I do see the tanish-yellow background for the body, and the light brown for the footer. However, you have no <header> element in the HTML so there is nothing to apply for that. If the "JavaJam Coffee House" text should have a background color, you can either move the color property to the `h1` rule or surround the <h1> tag with a <header> tag.

Comment: Okay, that was helpful - thank you! I reorganized my folder and somehow got it to work, so seems to have been an issue on that end. Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION

I recommend you change the  tag-selector in your stylesheet to ,
because there's no  tag in your html.

```html
body {background-color: #FCEBB6;
      color: #221811;
      font-family: verdana;}
      
h1 {background-color: #D2B48C;
        text-align: center;}
        
h1 {line-height: 200%;}

nav {text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;}
    
footer{background-color: #D2B48C;
      font-size: .60em;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;}
```

And then you could do some rearranging of the code

```
 h1 {background-color: #D2B48C;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 200%;}
```

### OPTION 2

simply enclose the 'h1' tag in your html in an 'header'

```
<header><h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1></header>
```